# gRPC installation fails at "make"

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am following the Built From Source [instructions](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/INSTALL.md) to install grpc

```
$ git clone -b $(curl -L https://grpc.io/release) https://github.com/grpc/grpc
```

*success*

```
$ cd grpc
```

*success*

```
$ git submodule update --init
```

*success*

```
$ make
```

*fails after building a few source files*

```
third_party/boringssl/crypto/rand/urandom.c:62:2: error: #error "system call number for getrandom is not the expected value"
#error "system call number for getrandom is not the expected value"
 ^
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/syscall.h:31:0,
from third_party/boringssl/crypto/rand/urandom.c:32:
third_party/boringssl/crypto/rand/urandom.c: In function ‘init_once’:
third_party/boringssl/crypto/rand/urandom.c:128:15: error: ‘__NR_getrandom’ undeclared (first use in this function)
syscall(SYS_getrandom, &dummy, sizeof(dummy), GRND_NONBLOCK);
         ^
third_party/boringssl/crypto/rand/urandom.c:128:15: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
third_party/boringssl/crypto/rand/urandom.c: In function ‘fill_with_entropy’:
third_party/boringssl/crypto/rand/urandom.c:258:21: error: ‘__NR_getrandom’ undeclared (first use in this function)
r = syscall(SYS_getrandom, out, len, 0 /* no flags */);
            ^
Makefile:2564: recipe for target '/home/usrnm/grpc/objs/opt/third_party/boringssl/crypto/rand/urandom.o' failed
make: *** [/home/usrnm/grpc/objs/opt/third_party/boringssl/crypto/rand/urandom.o] Error 1
```

OS: Linux 4.4.0-0 SMP Debian 4.4.16-1

GCC version: gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2

I couldn't find any open issues or any help about this error on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have better luck without the embedded BoringSSL. Try building with:

```
EMBED_OPENSSL=false make
```

If you get errors about missing packages, make sure you have [`libssl-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libssl-dev) installed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to happen while compiling [boringssl](https://opensource.google.com/projects/boringssl) . We use the version given by `$ git submodule`, which at the time of this writing is `be2ee342d3781ddb954f91f8a7e660c6f59e87e5 third_party/boringssl (version_for_cocoapods_7.0-526-gbe2ee342)`. Are you able to compile boringssl on its own?